# Vuejs - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm relatively new to Vuejs and I’ve been stuck on with the following error for a while now: (Appears when page loads)

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router
>             at Function.defineProperty ()
>             at Function.install (VM2179 vue-router.esm.js:526)
>             at Function.Vue.use (vue.js:4738)
>             at eval (VM2179 vue-router.esm.js:2447)
>             at Object../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js (VM2105 app.js:1615)
>             at __webpack_require__ (VM2105 app.js:712)
>             at fn (VM2105 app.js:95)
>             at eval (VM2178 index.js:3)
>             at Object../src/router/index.js (VM2105 app.js:2415)
>             at __webpack_require__ (VM2105 app.js:712)

This issue doesn't seem to be affecting the usability of the webapp and I’m pretty sure I’m not declaring Vue.use(Router) more than once…

Here is my index.js file: (in src/router)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Blog from '../components/Blog.vue'
import BlogPost from '../components/BlogPost.vue'

Vue.use(Router)
Vue.config.silent = true

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/blog',
      name: 'Blog',
      component: Blog
    },
    {
      path: '/blog/:slug',
      name: 'Blog-post',
      component: BlogPost
    }
  ]
})
```

app.ts: (in src, main entry point)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/simple_store'
import '../assets/app.css'
import './assets/main_logo.css'
import './assets/pages/page_header_animation.css'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Please help!
Thank you!!

Comment: It might be that your app is getting loaded twice on the same page?

Comment: I agree, import the router in you main.js with something like "import router from './router'", but not in your app.ts file.

Comment: It appears to me that `app.ts` IS the main js file. I assume also, that the `index.js` file you have mentioned is `./router/index.js` is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Daniel Yes app.ts is the main js file and index.js is in ./router/index.js

Comment: Hi @Dylan as mentioned above, app.ts is the main.js file (just named differently)

Comment: Do you happen to be including any `<script>` tags for Vue or vue-router in your `index.html` file (or any `.html` file)?

Comment: @Phil

Oh! I see it now, I did somehow include `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>` in my `index.html` file... This is where the problem was. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the [following code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/v3.0.1/dist/vue-router.esm.js#L2619) in `vue-router`

```
if (inBrowser && window.Vue) {
  window.Vue.use(VueRouter);
}
```

which is really only present for when you're including files in `<script>` blocks (ie, no build system).

Remove any `<script>` elements relating to Vue or related components; you don't need them when using Webpack.

Comment: What about when you're exposing vue to the window for the sake of allowing external scripts to use Vue?

Answer (score 12):

Solved!

In my `index.html` file, I had imported `vue` again:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Meko Deng</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Commenting that out did the trick!

Comment: Forget commenting it out, just delete the line :D

Comment: Yep Yep~~ Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you used Webpack and had forgotten set

```
externals: {
  Vue: 'vue'
}
```

In this case you had initialized vue and vue-router twice in the external CND and in the webpacks's lib.

Comment: Thank you! Wow just amazing, my knowledge about webpack's `externals` and what it does is really limited thus i've never quite understood why I got an error related to this single setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pretty sure that you are not using the below line two times.

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

Then this is happening because you added the script two times.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

remove duplicate script, Laravel by default add this script tag inside the head section of the app.blade.php file

Comment: When I remove this <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> from app.blade.php
the login page stops showing error, but other pages show blank, any idea?

Comment: Vue.use(VueRouter); check that router is define double time?

Comment: In my case it was an unclosed div at login.blade.php.
Thanks for helping.