# [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly. [Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I’m relatively new to Vuejs and I’m getting the following warnings every time I press a key:

```
[Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <HeaderComponent> at src\components\Header_Component.vue
         <App> at src\App.vue
           <Root>
```

and

```
[Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly.

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <HeaderComponent> at src\components\Header_Component.vue
         <App> at src\App.vue
           <Root>
```

These warnings do not seem to be affecting the usability at all though. I'm invoking neither $attrs or $listeners anywhere, I'm not sure where these warnings are coming from.

Here is my Header_Component.vue:

```
<template>
    <header class="header">
        <div class='nav nav-side nav-oneLine'>
            <a class='nav-link' href='#'><router-link @click.native="addClass(), setLogoTrue('project')" to='/Projects'>PROJECTS</router-link></a>
            <a class='nav-link' href='#'><router-link @click.native="addClass(), setLogoTrue('blog')" to='/Blog'>BLOG</router-link></a>
            <a class='nav-link' href='#'><router-link @click.native="addClass(), setLogoTrue('aboutme')" to='/Aboutme'>ABOUT ME</router-link></a>
            <a class='nav-link' href='#'><router-link @click.native="addClass(), setLogoTrue('resume')" to='/Resume'>RESUME</router-link></a>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return{
            logoTrue: <Object> {
                'main': true,
                'project': false,
                'blog': false,
                'aboutme': false,
                'resume': false
            },
            main: <boolean>true,
            header: <any>"",
            image: <any>"",
            h1: <any>"",
            h2: <any>"",
            nav: <any>"",
            logos: <any>"",
            break: <any>"",
        }
    },
    components: {
        insta, facebook, github, codepen, mainLogo, mainLogoSmall, test, projectsLogo, blogsLogo, aboutmeLogo, resumeLogo
    }
    methods:{
        addClass(){
            if (document.querySelector('.h2Active') == null && document.querySelector('.header_top') == null) {
                this.add_newClasses()
                this.emit_finished(true)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.remove_separators()
                }, 800) 
            } else {
                console.log('classes already exist!')
                this.$emit('reloadBackToTop')
            }        
        },
        remove_separators() {
            let breaker = document.getElementsByClassName('separator')

            while (breaker[0]) {
                this.nav.removeChild(breaker[0])
            }
        },
        setLogoTrue(target) {
            for (var key in this.logoTrue) {
                if (this.logoTrue.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    if (key == target) {
                        this.logoTrue[key] = true
                    } else {
                        this.logoTrue[key] = false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        apply_topClasses() {
            this.header.classList.add('header_top')
            this.image.classList.add('imgStatic_top')
            this.h1.classList.add('h1_name_top')
            this.h2.classList.add('h2_name_top')
            this.logos.classList.add('logo_links_top')
            this.nav.classList.add('nav-side_top')

            this.emit_finished(false)
        },
        add_newClasses() {
            if (window.innerWidth < 1060) {
                this.nav.classList.add('navActive_small')
                this.image.classList.add('imgActive_small')
            } else {
                this.nav.classList.add('navActive')
                this.image.classList.add('imgActive')
            }
            this.logos.classList.add('logo_linksActive')
            this.header.classList.add('headerActive')
            this.h1.classList.add('h1Active')
            this.h2.classList.add('h2Active')

            this.image.classList.remove('imgStatic')
        },
        emit_finished(delay:boolean) {
            if (delay) {
                setTimeout (() => {
                    this.$emit('finishedLoading')
                    console.log('finished_loading')
                }, 2000)
            } else {
                console.log('here')
                this.$emit('finishedLoading')
            }
        },
        adjust_clientWidth() {
            if (window.innerWidth < 1060) {
                // this.remove_separators()
                let bigActive = document.getElementsByClassName('big-nav')
                let navActive = document.getElementsByClassName('navActive')
                if (bigActive.length > 0) {
                    this.nav.classList.add('small-nav')
                    this.nav.classList.remove('big-nav')

                    this.image.classList.add('small-img')
                    this.image.classList.remove('big-img')

                } else if (navActive.length > 0) {
                    this.nav.classList.add('small-nav')
                    this.nav.classList.remove('nav-side')
                    this.nav.classList.remove('navActive')

                    this.image.classList.add('small-img')
                    this.image.classList.remove('imgActive')
                }
            } else {
                let smallActive = document.getElementsByClassName('small-nav')
                let smallnavActive = document.getElementsByClassName('navActive_small')
                if (smallActive.length > 0) {
                    this.nav.classList.add('big-nav')
                    this.nav.classList.remove('small-nav')

                    this.image.classList.add('big-img')
                    this.image.classList.remove('small-img')                     

                } else if (smallnavActive.length > 0) {
                    this.nav.classList.add('big-nav')
                    this.nav.classList.remove('nav-side')
                    this.nav.classList.remove('navActive_small')

                    this.image.classList.add('big-img')
                    this.image.classList.remove('imgActive_small')                    
                }
            }
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        window.addEventListener('resize',this.adjust_clientWidth)
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.header = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0]
        this.image = document.getElementsByClassName('img')[0]
        this.h1 = document.getElementsByClassName('h1_name')[0]
        this.h2 = document.getElementsByClassName('h2_name')[0]
        this.nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0]
        this.logos = document.getElementsByClassName('logo_links')[0]  

        if (window.location.hash != "#/") {
            this.remove_separators()
            if (window.location.hash == "#/Projects") {
                this.setLogoTrue('project')
            } else if (window.location.hash.includes("#/Blog") || window.location.hash.includes("#/blog")) {
                this.setLogoTrue('blog')
            } else if (window.location.hash == "#/Aboutme") {
                this.setLogoTrue('aboutme')
            } else if (window.location.hash == "#/Resume") {
                this.setLogoTrue('resume')
            }
            this.apply_topClasses()
        }
    }
})
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
(...)
</style>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209717/vuejs-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-redefine-property-router Fixed!

Comment: Unless anyone has firsthand experience with this specific problem, it's going to be difficult to help you without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 8):

As you probably already figured out from another question, I am posting an answer here to save some time everybody else.

The issue with these kind of errors is usually because you import Vue more than once. First in your main app and then also in your component file.
So removing the line *import Vue from 'vue'* from your *Header_Component.vue* will resolve the issue.
But you will have to change the way you are declaring the component to this:

```
<script lang="ts">
//import Vue from 'vue' <-- Commented the import line

export default {  // <-- Removed Vue.extend()
    data() {
        return{
            logoTrue: <Object> {
                'main': true,
                'project': false,
                'blog': false,
                'aboutme': false,
                'resume': false
            },
            main: <boolean>true,
            header: <any>"",
            image: <any>"",
            h1: <any>"",
            h2: <any>"",
            nav: <any>"",
            logos: <any>"",
            break: <any>"",
        }
    }
    ...more code...
}
</script>
```

[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) is more about single file components.

Comment: In my case, I had to delete two scripts from my index.html: https://unpkg.com/vue and https://unpkg.com/vue-material and it solved the problem because I had already imported Vue from my main.js

Comment: In my case, micro-frontends, needed to add the Vue to the share modules

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to remove `Vue.extend`. There can be two other reasons why this is happening. Either because Vue is imported from multiple locations.

Or this problem can be because webpack isn't handling Vue as it should and thinks it is an external. So if you go to the file `webpack.config.js` or `webpack.renderer.config.js`, as appropriate, and remove Vue from the `externals` section, then it will start working again.

More information [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59265173/5363308).

Answer (score 0):

remove import Vue from 'vue' from Header_Component.vue