# Vue warn $listeners and $attrs is readonly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I am getting a lot of Vue warnings saying $listeners is readonly or $attrs is readonly and related to different Bootstrap items or to .

For example:

```
[Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

found in

---> <BDropdown>
       <Display>
         <App>
           <Root>
```

I am very sure it has something to do with loading the Vue instance twice somehow, but I don't really know, how to do it any other way, so that the routing still works.

In my main.js the code is as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import firebase from 'firebase';
import './components/firebaseInit';
import store from './store';
import { i18n } from './plugins/i18n.js'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import VueCarousel from 'vue-carousel';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(VueCarousel);

let app;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      store,
      i18n,
      components: { App },
      template: '<App/>'
    })
  }
})
```

My router/index.js code looks as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import firebaseApp from '@/components/firebaseInit'

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'display',
      component: Display
    },
  ...
  ]
})

// Nav Guards
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // check for requiredAuth
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // check if NOT logged in
    ...
    } else {
      // proceed to route
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
})

export default router;
```

As the sample errors come from Display.vue, here is an extract of that code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-row>
      <b-input-group prepend="Category">
        <b-dropdown v-bind:text="currentCategory">
          <b-dropdown-item @click="categroyChanged('All')">All</b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item v-for="c in categories" v-bind:key="c" @click="categoryChanged(c)">{{c}}</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-dropdown>
      </b-input-group>
    </b-row>
    <div class="row" v-for="i in Math.ceil(products.length / 3)" v-bind:key="i">
      <div v-for="product in products.slice((i - 1) * 3, i * 3)" v-bind:key="product.id" class="col-md-4 col-6 my-1">
        <b-card 
          v-bind:img-src="product.thumbUrl"
          img-fluid
          img-alt="image"
          overlay>
          <div slot="footer">
            <small class="text-muted">{{product.name}}<br />{{product.price}} VND</small>   
          </div>
            <router-link v-bind:to="{name: 'view-product', params: {product_id: product.product_id}}" class="secondary-content">
              <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
            </router-link>
            <router-link v-if="isEmployee" v-bind:to="{name: 'edit-product', params: {product_id: product.product_id}}" class="secondary-content">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </router-link>
            <button @click='addToCart(product)' class='button is-info'><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></button>
        </b-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>        
import firebaseApp from './firebaseInit'
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'display',
  data () {
    return {
      txtSearch: null,
      isLoggedIn: false,
      currentUser: false,
      isEmployee: false,
      products: []
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    var db = firebaseApp.firestore();
      db.collection('products').get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
              'product_id': doc.id,
              'article_number': doc.data().article_number,
              'barcode': doc.data().barcode,
              'category': doc.data().category,
              'colour': doc.data().colour,
              'description': doc.data().description,
              'name': doc.data().name,
              'name_ger': doc.data().name_ger,
              'price': doc.data().price,
              'size': doc.data().size,
              'thumbUrl': doc.data().thumbUrl,
          }
          this.products.push(data)
        })
      }) 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['addToCart']),

    ... many methods ...

  }
}
</script>
```

How can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem ? It's occurring to me now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two common reasons why this can happen:

### Multiple Vue Locations

This can be due to contradictory locations of where you are importing Vue from, in different files, as others have said. So you might have both `import Vue from 'vue'` and perhaps `import Vue from 'vue.runtime.esm'` in your code, for example.

But this can [result in multiple instances of Vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue/issues/201#issuecomment-484452281), which will cause these errors.

The solution in this case is to use `import Vue from 'vue'` everywhere in your code, and then alias it in your packaging system (webpack, Parcel, rollup etcetera). An example of this in `webpack.config.js`, or  `webpack.renderer.config.js` if you're using Electron, would be:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

See [more examples in the Vue documents](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only).

### White Listing

This can also be because of a need for Vue to be whitelisted as **not** one of the `externals` in webpack, for example.

It is worth noting that changes in Bootstrap Vue from 2.0 to a later version, definitely by 2.15 (and possibly earlier), caused this same problem to occur.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  externals: [
    'fast-glob',
    'jquery',
    'bunyan',
    'yaml',
    'vue',              // Remove this
    'bootstrap-vue',    // Remove this
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Removing them from externals is important.

Comment: The `$attrs is readonly` warning brought me here. As a bonus, aliasing fixed another issue that I was having with error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '$vnode')`, with previous warnings: `onMounted is called when there is no active component...` and `globally imported h() can only be invoked...`. Tricky business!

Answer (score 2):

After chasing this for an hour, I realized that a component that I had `imported` was also accessing `Vue`. At the top of that file was `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'`. Every other file was simply doing `import Vue from 'vue'`, which was the source of my double-import.

Different javascript packagers have different ways of resolving duplicates. For WebPack, the [Resolve Configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) might be helpful in the case of dependencies importing different instances of Vue.

Comment: This can also be the resolution to `[Vue warn]: this.$store not defined in component`.

Answer (score 0):

This was my case (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62262296/4202997) but I'll repeat it here to save you time: I was importing vue from a CDN . I simply removed the script and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the duplicated instances were caused by some Vue plugins importing the Vue instance differently than how I was doing in my project. I managed to fix it by adding the following to my Webpack config:

```js
    externals: {
      // Stubs out `require('vue')` so it returns `global.Vue`
      vue: 'Vue',
    },
```

Hope it can help anyone struggling with the same issue :)